# Printing shows blank diagonal cutoff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, printing

I'm trying to make a printable church songbook:

- Two columns
- The html page is rendered from rails, but with each song being a react component

The view has this code:

```
<div class='print-book'>
  <%= @song_data.sort_by { |data| data[:reference].index.to_i }.map do |song_data| %>
    <div class='print-song'>
      <div class="song-number"><%= song_data[:reference].index %></div>
      <%= react_component(
        'SongDisplay',
        lyrics: song_data[:song].lyrics
      ) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.print-book {
  column-count: 2;
}

.print-song {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.print-section {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

But as you can see from the screenshot, when I try to print, the preview shows a diagonal cut in the page, blanking out a big chunk of the page.

Any ideas on what is causing this? In the html (not print preview) the songs are shown fine.

[image: Broken Preview]